# R How to convert milliseconds from origin to date and keep the milliseconds

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, milliseconds

I realize there are several other questions similar to this, but all the answers I have seen suggest dividing a UNIX timestamp in milliseconds by 1000 for R to handle it properly (for example, 1506378449 instead of 1506378448618).

Is there a way to convert it without dividing by 1000 and keep those fractional seconds?

What I have tried so far does not work:

```
as.POSIXct(1506378448618, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = 
"America/Chicago", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

comes back NA, and it similarly does so with %OS1, 2, 3, etc.

```
anytime(1506378448618, tz = "America/Chicago")
```

and

```
as_datetime(1506378448618, tz = "America/Chicago")
```

both come back with times far into the future ("49705-03-26 12:56:58 CDT")

The best answer I can come up with is to split the string and do something like:

```
as_datetime(1506378448, tz = "America/Chicago") + .618
```

Which is fine, but it seems like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

`as.POSIXct(...)` does in fact keep track of fractional seconds. You can print fractions of seconds using the appropriate `format` string.

For example to print the first 3 digits you can do

```
t <- 1506378448618;
format(as.POSIXct(t / 1000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "America/Chicago"), "%H:%M:%OS3")
#[1] "17:27:28.618"
```

Note: The reason why `as.POSIXct(..., format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")` results in `NA` is simply because your input object `1506378448618` does not have format `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"`. You can however specify a `format` string when printing the `POSIXct` object.

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing out the issue with formatting, I think that's where I was stuck. 

format(as.POSIXct(t / 1000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "America/Chicago"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")

provides just what I needed. Thank you!